# Uploading files with Spring

Tags: spring, file-upload

I'm uploading multiple Excel files to a server. For files, I use the `CommonsMultiPartFile` class. My problem is that when I try to handle file uploaded like

```
  File KUStiedosto = new File(form.getKUS().getOriginalFilename());
          form.getKUS().transferTo(KUStiedosto);


            Workbook KUStk = Workbook.getWorkbook(KUStiedosto);
            Sheet KUSl = KUStk.getSheet(0);
            for (int r = 7; r < KUSl.getRows() - 1; r++) {
```

I get

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 2601401KUS1007.xls (Access is denied)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:423)
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo(CommonsMultipartFile.java:137)
    fi.utu.seurantaraporttisuodatin.service.Kustannusraportti.calculateKUS(Kustannusraportti.java:27)
    fi.utu.seurantaraporttisuodatin.service.Raportti.createReportContext(Raportti.java:424)
    fi.utu.seurantaraporttisuodatin.controller.FormController.onSubmit(FormController.java:68)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
```

What do I have to do with my server's rights or is there something else too? I'm using Netbeans and a Tomcat server attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to give the write permission to the user running the server (tomcat?) for the folder where you are placing the file.

Comment: `@mjgirl` your machine. It depends on whether it windows or linux. And it better be done by an administrator, if you don't feel comfortable with OS stuff. Or ask on serverfault.com

Comment: So it is not TomCat's own file? I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

When you call `CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo()`, you're passing a reference to a `File` location to which it should write the uploaded file. However, your tomcat server does not have write permission to that file.

You need to find out which user Tomcat is running as, and make sure that user has write access to that file location.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my Windows 7 box. Its mainly because of the access restrictions.

You have 2 options:

1. I could able to write the file to my
   Desktop though. Try writing the file
   to your desktop to check whether
   your code works.
2. Run the Tomcat as Administrator. Copy the War to your tomcat's
   webapps folder.  Type Windows Key
   and Search for cmd.  Right click on
   the cmd.exe and run it as
   Administrator.  Now navigate to the
   Tomcat's bin folder and run
   startup.bat. Now you could able to save the file in any location.